# Angular recursive dependace between two services

Tags: angular

FooService needs BarService and BarService needs FooService.

**Result when injecting both on constructors:**

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BarService
```

Comment: Got code? You may need a 3rd service instead of both of those services needing each other.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: @Vega how to have both services that call each other ?

Comment: Semantically you cannot, it tells about your code structural weakness.You have reorganize your code :)

Answer (score 0):

[Forward Ref.](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#break-circularities-with-a-forward-class-reference-forwardref)

> Break circularities with a forward class reference (forwardRef)
>
> This isn't usually a problem, especially if you adhere to the
>   recommended one class per file rule. But sometimes circular references
>   are unavoidable. You're in a bind when class 'A' refers to class 'B'
>   and 'B' refers to 'A'. One of them has to be defined first.